# Dto to entity and dto from entity

Tags: node.js, rest, mapping, nestjs

In my app I need multi times map from the Entity (Database model) to DTO (local object)

Most times, Dto have the same names as the entity

For example The Entity

```
export class CompanyModel extends BaseEntity {
  constructor(init?: Partial<CompanyModel>) {
  }
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ length: 500 })
  name: string;

  @Column({ length: 500, unique: true })
  email: string;




  ....

}
```

The DTO

```
export class Company {
  @ApiProperty()
  id: string;


  @ApiProperty()
  email: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  name: string;
...
}
```

Now I add static function `toModel` and `fromModel`

```
  static toModel(companyDto :CreateCompanyDto ) : CompanyModel {
    const companyModel =  new CompanyModel();

    const {name, email,..... } = companyDto;
    companyModel.name = name;
    companyModel.email =email
   
.....
    return companyModel;
}
```

What is the best solution for mapping DTO to ENTITY in nestjs / node

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, it depend, what other things do you plan with your dtos. In my application I put a lot of pre- or post-processing on my dto-s. Here is an example, where I want to restrict the format of the email property:

```js
export class Company {
  @ApiProperty()
  id: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @Transform(value => value.toLowerCase())
  email: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  name: string;
...
}
```

If you plan to use these transformations, I suggest to use the [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer): `classToPlain`, `plainToClass` methods, so you can safely and effectively transform your data from the dto object to an entity instance. You can even put different transformations on both of your classes.

```js
static toModel(companyDto: CreateCompanyDto ): CompanyModel {
  const data = classToPlain(companyDto);
  return plainToClass(CompanyModel, data);
}
```

You can find more information on the link I mentioned above. It can even help you, how to [control the properties](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#skipping-all-properties-of-the-class) on your dtos or how to [change their behaviour](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#using-groups-to-control-excluded-properties) based on different use-cases.

Comment: If my entity has 3 properties {a,b,c}, and my dto contain 2 propretis {a,b},  and i wrote {const data = classToPlain(entity); return plainToClass(Dto,data); I got the all 3 properties {a,b,c}, so how does it works? thanks

Comment: You have to expose properties explicitely and skip non-whitelisted properties. You can read more here: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#enforcing-type-safe-instance

Comment: Using plainToClass is the best solution to use in NestJS @24sharon